# why the following fails

Tags: c#, .net

```
 Uri test = new Uri("http%3A%2F%2F100.100.1.1%3A8080");
```

An unhandled exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

Anyone know why I cannot pass in a URL encoded string to the constructor of Uri?

Comment: The encoding is meant for the querystring data, not the URL itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not escape it and try using http://100.100.1.1:8080.

Answer (score 1):

The Uri Constructor requires the String to be a valid [RFC2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) URI. There's this [Uri.CheckSchemeName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.checkschemename.aspx) to check if your passed URI is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a `%` before the second `2F`?  Try passing the string through a URL un-encoder and make sure the result is what you expected.

Comment: @user496949: Ah, ok, no problem.